# Python. Apply getter to every attribute of a class

Tags: python, oop, attributes, getter

I have some class with attributes:

```
class Elements(Locators):
    tab_accept = (By.ID, 'droppableExample-tab-accept')
    box_acceptable = (By.ID, 'acceptable')
```

Which inherits from base class **Locators**:

```
class Locators:
    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return WebElement(object.__getattribute__(self, item))
```

Initial idea was, that when I call an attribute within other classes, it would be returned with applied changes:

```
Elements.tab_accept -> WebElement(Elements.tab_accept)
```

But it returns it unchanged:

```
Elements.tab_accept -> Tuple[By, str]
```

How can I achieve a desired effect without writing every attribute with @property decorator?

Comment: `__getattribute__` works with objects. Try `Elements().tab_accept`

Comment: @rdas, do you, perhaps, know if it is possible to get rid of instantiating of a class? Some dunder like __call__ or __new__?

Comment: You might consider using `__init_subclass__` to pre-process the attribute values when the class is defined, rather than modifying the attribute value on access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new `WebElement` every time the attribute is accessed, would it make sense to give the attribute a `WebElement` value in `__init_subclass__` instead?

Something like

```
class Locators:
    def __init_subclass(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        for k, v in cls.__dict__:
            setattr(cls, k, WebElement(v))

class Elements(Locators):
    tab_accept = (By.ID, 'droppableExample-tab-accept')
    box_acceptable = (By.ID, 'acceptable')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rdas:

> __getattribute__ works with objects. Try **Elements().tab_accept**